# how can we use unitedinternet.portal.selenium.utils in selenium 2 or webdrivers

Tags: selenium-webdriver

how can we use unitedinternet.portal.selenium.utils in selenium 2 or webdrivers.How can we log results using this utility

Answer (score 0):

See here for usage examples: http://loggingselenium.sourceforge.net/usage.html